# BleMesh model to handle 4bytes of data

Tags: c, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, nimble

I am using Nimble BleMesh stack on Esp32 and my application needs to transfer 4bytes of data between client and server node. Which mesh model should be used in this case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is a Bluetooth Mesh Model overview on the Bluetooth SIG site: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/1903_Mesh-Models-Overview_FINAL.pdf